# MySQL, temporary on disk table on primary key retrieval?

Tags: mysql, innodb, primary-key, temporary-tables

MySQL 5.5.24, Windows 7 64-bit.

I've InnoDB table with primary key defined on three columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `common_descriptions` (
  `object_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `object_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `lang_code` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `object` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `object_holder` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`lang_code`,`object`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And I'm executing fairly simple query which (in my opinion) should use index to return rows

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE object_id, lang_code, object
from common_descriptions
limit 1
```

yet it creates 10 temporary tables of which 3 are on disk temporary tables (confirmed multiple times by monitoring `show status like '%tmp%';`). `object` column seems to trigger creation of temporary tables. When I replace `object` (varchar(12)) with `description` (mediumtext) temporary table is not created. `explain extended` of above query:

```
mysql> explain extended select SQL_NO_CACHE object_id, lang_code, object from co
mmon_descriptions limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: common_descriptions
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 47
          ref: NULL
         rows: 49765
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Both `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` are set to 16M.

After reading documentation on temporary tables (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) I don't see any good explanation on why temporary tables would be created in this case. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## OBSERVATION #1

You need to look at what the Query Optimizer sees and what it is interpreting

First, look carefully at the query

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE object_id, lang_code, object
from common_descriptions
limit 1
```

There is no WHERE clause. It is generating a temp table for an unbounded result set.

LIMIT has low precedence in the eyes of the Query Optimizer. Why ?

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)

Another section of that same page says the following:

> With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return
>   from the beginning of the result set:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5; # Retrieve first 5 rows
>
> In other words, LIMIT row_count is equivalent to LIMIT 0, row_count.

Once you use the clause `LIMIT`, the `SELECT` must generate a result first. Your result has no boundary (no WHERE clause). The LIMIT is applied afterwards.

That explains the temp table creation.

## OBSERVATION #2

You mentioned the following in your question

> When I replace object (varchar(12)) with description (mediumtext) temporary table is not created

According to the [MySQL Documentation on the Temp Tables (your link)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)

> Some conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table, in
>   which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:
>
> - Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table
> - Presence of any string column in a GROUP BY or DISTINCT clause larger than 512 bytes
> - Presence of any string column with a maximum length larger than 512 (bytes for binary strings, characters for nonbinary strings) in the
>     SELECT list, if UNION or UNION ALL is used
> - The SHOW COLUMNS and The DESCRIBE statements use BLOB as the type for some columns, thus the temporary table used for the results is an
>     on-disk table.

The problem has a lot to do with the result set and the first bulletpoint (`Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table`) Since TEXT field cannot occupy an in-memory temp table, it goes straight to disk. That's just the tip of the iceberg.

When you ran

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE object_id, lang_code, object
from common_descriptions
limit 1
```

you were essentially read the entire row. How come ?

The `common_descriptions` is defined with the InnoDB Storage Engine

The primary key of an InnoDB table sits in a logical structure call the Clustered Index ([**internally it is called `gen_clust_index`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html), which can only be seen when running `SHOW ENGINE INNOD STATUS\G`)

That document says

> Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the row data is on the same page where the index search leads. If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record. (For example, MyISAM uses one file for data rows and another for index records

Since you accessed every column of the PRIMARY KEY (`object_id, lang_code, object`), internally you were essentially fetching every row (including `description`) which explains why a PRIMARY KEY retrieval still yielded a temp table on disk. When you changed the SELECT list (`object_id, lang_code, description`) things evident changed. a little. An in-memory temp table would not have been made. Why?

[MySQL Documentation says this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html):

> When the server creates an internal temporary table (either in memory or on disk), it increments the Created_tmp_tables status variable. If the server creates the table on disk (either initially or by converting an in-memory table) it increments the Created_tmp_disk_tables status variable.

Thus, `Created_tmp_tables` would not have incremented because of the description being `mediumtext`. It went straight to disk. `Created_tmp_disk_tables` would have incremented instead.

## SUMMARY

Many factors were involved

- LIMIT used again a result set with no WHERE clause
- InnoDB Clustered Index
- `description` being `MEDIUMTEXT`

## SUGGESTION

Try adding an `ORDER BY`

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE object_id, lang_code, object
from common_descriptions
order by object_id, lang_code, object
limit 1;
```

I hae seen it when done against a single column PRIMARY KEY.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: First of all thanks for **great** answer. I have few other questions though, and here's one of them: When I'm selecting `object_id, lang_code, description` (description is `mediumtext`) neither in memory nor on disk temporary tables are being created (they are **not** being used) which seems strange to me and contradicts Your expectations too. I expected mediumtext to force creation of temporary table (again, confirmed with `show status like '%tmp%';`)

Comment: Also, haven't You meant 'column' instead of 'row' in "Since you accessed every column of the PRIMARY KEY (object_id, lang_code, object), internally you were essentially fetching every **row**[...] "

Comment: +1 @RolandoMySQLDBA nice answer  "When working with an database, you must understand it's rules.
To destroy an database, you must break it."

Comment: Regarding the second comment, When I said `Since you accessed every column of the PRIMARY KEY (object_id, lang_code, object), internally you were essentially fetching every **row**[...] `, I did mean every row. Or rather, every column in every row. I said every row for 2 reasons: 1) InnoDB stores index pages of the PRIMARY KEY and data pages together or as close as possible in the Clustered Index. 2) Since there is no WHERE clause, all rows com along for ride before LIMIT is applied..

Comment: As regards the first comment, my conjecture would be : since every column is being read from the Clustered Index, perhaps a temp table is not necessary even with a `MEDIUMTEXT` field.